# Symfony2: Routing priority

Tags: php, symfony

is there anyway to prioritize routes in Symfony2?

i'm using annotation it looks like this

**Controllers**

```
//TestController.php

/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/a", name="test_a")
     */
   .....

//DummyController.php
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class DummyController extends Controller
{
    /**
      * @Route("/{varA}/{varB}", name="dummy_one")
      */
   .....
```

**Config**

```
//routing.yml

acme_bundle:
    resource: "@Acme/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

**Goal**

```
URL      , Actual              , Goal
/test/a  , DummyController     , TestController  //Wrong
/test/b  , DummyController     , DummyController //Good
```

How can i force TestController to be tested first ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need such a dummy controller? Fallback all the routes doesn't feel like a correct idea.

Comment: not a fall back `DummyController` routes are dynamically generated by the user while the other is fixed by the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So Symfony will consume the controllers in an alphabetical order and will add the routes one by one.

there is no way up to add priority at the moment without using another bundle for that `currently version 2.5`

https://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing is a great bundle if you are looking for advanced routing.

Answer (score 9):

from your example i can assume that your dummy and test controller are in the same bundle, if this is the case then you just lists the controllers in that bundle individually in your routing.yml.  the order you list them is the order they will be checked.

```
acme_test:
    resource: "@Acme/Controller/TestController.php"
    type:     annotation

acme_dummy:
    resource: "@Acme/Controller/DummyController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

if they are in different bundles, just list the bundle with the test controller first.

see the symfony routing doc for details.    http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation

Comment: My project is kind of medium/large so if i follow this approach, things will get missy.

Comment: you don't have to do it for every bundle, just the one with the your test and dummy controllers.

Comment: But what i will be doing basically is to write 2 routes for the same method. feels like i will be repeating my self. if this will be the only solution i will consider it but still i'm looking for other alternatives, thank you very much for your answer, i will mark it as accept it if i get no other solution.

Comment: How do we do this in symfony4 when AppBundle no longer exists? I have this; app_login:
    resource: "@App/Controller/SecurityController.php"
    type:     annotation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reorder everything. Just overwrite the rules for DummyController at the desired ranking. You can do this by creating a route to the controller at the end of your routing.yml. 
So in your routing.yml as the last lines you will add:

```
app_dummy:
    ressource: "@YourBundle/Controller/DummyController.php
    type:     annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as it might help other users viewing this question. As of Symfony 5.1, a priority can be assigned to each route:

```
#[Route(path: '/', name: 'home')]
public function home(): Response
{
    return $this->render('home.html.twig');
}

#[Route(path: '/about', name: 'about', priority: 10)]
public function about(): Response
{
    return $this->render('about.html.twig');
}
```

In this case (it's just a dummy example), the `about` route with a priority of 10 will be evaluated before the `home` route, which has the default priority of 0.

Check out the feature introduction on the [Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority).