# How to change priority in Symfony3 routing.yml

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml, symfony-3.1

I have the following generic routing on my symfony project as in (routing.yml):

```
appsite2:
    path:     /{req}/{var}
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:index}
```

However, it overwrites the routing `api/doc` as:

```
NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/doc
```

So how can I change the first routing and put exception for `{var}`, something like: `if({req}/{var} != '/api/doc')`?

Note: I already tried to change the order of the 2 routes and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your `AppBundle:DefaultController`?

Comment: Is the NelmioApiDocBundle routing defined in the same yaml? I think the routing system will fire which ever matches first, so you could try that block above the other block in your yaml.

Comment: You can see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927044/symfony2-routing-priority. It seems you can't define routes priority for the moment.  Symfony order it by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following regex to exclude the word "doc" as the following :

```
appsite2:
path:     /{req}/{var}
defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:index}
requirements:
        var: '^((?!doc).)*$'
```